# Lots of output from Cucumber tests when using Poltergeist/PhantomJS

Tags: cucumber, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I am seeing lots of output when running my cucumber tests using Poltergeist. I have most options set to false in my env.rb but I still continue to see things. Any ideas on how I can turn off this additional logging?

Below is the output that I am seeing.

```
MIXPANEL REQUEST:
[object Object]
MIXPANEL NOTIFICATION CHECK
MIXPANEL PEOPLE REQUEST:
[object Object]
MIXPANEL PEOPLE REQUEST:
[object Object]
MIXPANEL REQUEST:========================== 99 ==================================> |  ETA: 00:00:03
[object Object]
MIXPANEL NOTIFICATION CHECK
MIXPANEL PEOPLE REQUEST:
[object Object]
 674/674 |================================= 100 ==================================>| Time: 00:11:44

84 scenarios (84 passed)
674 steps (674 passed)
11m44.357s
```

**My env.rb file**

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    options = {
        :js_errors => false,
        :phantomjs_logger => false,
        :timeout => 120,
        :debug => false,
        :phantomjs_options => ['--load-images=no', '--disk-cache=false'],
        :inspector => false,
    }
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
```

**Additional Info**

- capybara (2.1.0)
- cucumber (1.3.15)
- poltergeist (1.6.0)
- PhantomJS = 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:phantomjs_logger` is where the output will be logged. Try specifying a log file, as the default is STDOUT e.g.

```
:phantomjs_logger => File.open("log/test_phantomjs.log", "a")
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! It looks like the :phantomjs_logger => false is being ignored. https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/436